# How do I close a thread properly after usage in Java Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, garbage-collection

I am creating a thread in Java for Android using following code:

```
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String TAG = "WorkerThread";
                Integer c = 1;
                MainActivity.logInMainThread(TAG, "Initial state of Worker thread is " + Thread.currentThread().getState().toString(), "DEBUG");
                Authentication authentication = new Authentication();
                Boolean result = authentication.authenticate(bindDN, password);
                Validation validate = MainActivity.getValidationObject(c);
                validate.setResult(result);
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                TAG = null;
                c = null;
                authentication = null;
                result = null;
                validate = null;
                System.gc();
                return;
            }
        });
```

As you can see I tried using Thread.interrupt and clearing all the variables and calling the Garbage Collector and returning but I still receive

```
W/System: A resource failed to call close.
```

after the thread is done, how do I close it properly? If I call Thread.stop it throws an Error and the method is deprecated, same with Thread.destroy.

How can I close my thread and stop it from becoming a corpse?

Comment: A thread ends when it completes its execution. This means that when it executes its last line of code - it dies. So just make sure nothing is stopping it from fully executing and you're good.

Comment: Unless a thread is terminated in an unexpected way or is somehow detached from the process, there shouldn't be a need for you to clean up manually. As soon as the work load is done, the JVM handles clean up automatically.

Comment: @QBrute: minor nitpick: since this is tagged Android, there's no JVM involved. The equivalent task would be done by the Android Runtime.

Comment: @JoachimSauer oops yes, sorry you're right

Comment: Do you get any more information in the logs? Does it tell what resource has failed to be closed? Don't filter the logcat because you may miss something important.

Comment: Neither, setting variables to `null` nor calling `interrupt()` or `System.gc()` is necessary. Since there is no `close()` method, your experience that calling it “throws an Error” is questionable. A thread will be cleaned up automatically after it ran, however, that requires that you *start* it in the first place.

Comment: I do start the thread a couple line further in the Code. I tried using stop(), not close as there doesnt seem to be a close() function avaliable, and receive following error: 'E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4
    Process: com.example.test, PID: 7995
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:986)
        at com.example.test.credentials.Validation.Validate(Validation.java:38)...'

Comment: Trying to use close shows that there is no method inside Thread called close():

Cannot resolve method 'close' in 'Thread'

Comment: Out of curiosity: why exactly do you want to use raw Threads in Android anyway? Why aren't you looking for the more idiomatic ways to do concurrency in Android? See https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html for example.

Comment: It seemed like a logical way to do it. Even if concurrency is a better way to solve this I would still like to know why I am getting the Error after opening the thread and why  cant seem to close it successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A thread should terminate when it's run method (or the Runnable's run method) terminates.

Your cleanup is the last few expressions in the run method, and it may be they are never executed since is the thread gets interrupted (an InterruptedException is thrown). You are doing it by invoking `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();`.

So your run method should look like

```
public void run() {
    // at least declare the variables so their scope lasts until the finally block
    String TAG = "WorkerThread";
    Integer c = 1;
    Authentication authentication = null;

    try { // perform your actions
        MainActivity.logInMainThread(TAG, "Initial state of Worker thread is " + Thread.currentThread().getState().toString(), "DEBUG");
        authentication = new Authentication();
        Boolean result = authentication.authenticate(bindDN, password);
        Validation validate = MainActivity.getValidationObject(c);
        validate.setResult(result);
    } finally { // perform your cleanup
        TAG = null;
        c = null;
        authentication = null;
        result = null;
        validate = null;
        System.gc();
    }
}
```

Comment: Adjusted the Code as recommended but still receiving 
W/System: A resource failed to call close.

Comment: I do not have enough information, but your cleanup may be incomplete. Check what else might need a cleanup. You could try to comment out the lines in the run method to see which of them opens something that should be closed again.